# Too quick to put questions on hold?

Tags: discussion

I think often a question is downvoted/put on hold/closed because it:

- Has a simple answer that seems obvious not warranting a 'real answer'.

(In which case, just answer the question!).

- Applies to a general situation that can't be covered by a single answer.

(In which case give an outline or different options or approaches).

Examples:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/whats-the-best-way-to-structure-an-email-that-has-suggestions-for-workplace-pro
On hold (unclear) and -3 votes.

Question is asking for a format/template for writing an email. 
Possible answers are either provide a template, or agree or clarify the answer the OP gave.

[Underpaid and overworked, how should I approach my boss?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/underpaid-and-overworked-how-must-i-approach-my-boss)

On hold (opinion based) and -1 votes.

Guy in what appears to be a bad work situation.

Answer could a be a outline of your options:

eg.

- Quitting is an option.
- How to bring this up with your boss. (eg. outline the additional work you're doing, and the role you've played in improving the company, this is deserving of a significant raise).

[When is it okay to consult others on work I'm doing (after being told I take up too much of their time)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/when-is-it-okay-to-consult-others-on-work-im-doing-after-being-told-i-take-up)

+2 votes and on hold (opinion based)

Guy being told off for asking too many questions in work place.

Answer could be a structure around asking colleagues for work, or an outline of what generally acceptable work practises are.

Placing the questions on hold makes it because they can't then be answered, when someone might have a good answer.

Comment: Hey user, I think the close issue can be covered in the linked question in Jim's comment. For the comment about telling people they can quit, [we hold 'quit your job' answers to a much higher standard](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/is-quit-your-job-an-acceptable-answer?lq=1) and generally discourage them. *"On Hold"* just means the question needs to be improved a bit and then will be reopened. You can contribute with [edits of yours own](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/how-should-we-adjust-our-approach-to-editing-to-minimize-conflicts)